# How to remove exponential values in excel when exporting data from a gridview?c#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, excel, datagrid

I want to avoid the exponential values in Excel sheet.

I am exporting the data from a Data Grid View to excel. In the Data Grid View, the values are displaying in the decimal format. But after exporting the data to excel sheet, the values in the excel sheet are displaying in Exponential format.

Code for getting values from Data Grid:

```
 for (i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; i++)
                {
                    for (j = 0; j <= dataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1; j++)
                    {
                        DataGridViewCell cell = dataGridView1[j, i];
                        ws.Cells[i + 8, j + 1] = cell.Value;
                    }
                    range = ws.get_Range("A" + (i + 8).ToString(), "L" + (i + 8).ToString());
                    range.EntireColumn.AutoFit();
                    range.HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignLeft;
                }
```

Help me..............
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert cell value into `double/decimal` type and then use `ToString("N2")` or `ToString("C2")` method to convert back to string type.